# Geo sorting and distance calculation in ElasticSearch not working

Tags: geolocation, elasticsearch, geopoints

**UPDATE** I've also updated the mapping to include **pin** as the examples seem to suggest. Also, here's an temporary instance with some data to work with: https://21991e47cdc7caa8000.qbox.io/profiles/lead/_search

I've followed the [instructions by ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/geo-location-and-search/). Using this request:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://21991e47cdc7caa8000.qbox.io/profiles/lead/_search', 
        method: 'GET', 
        data: {
            sort: [{
                _geo_distance: {
                    "pin.location": [49.8998, -97.1375], 
                    order: "asc", 
                    unit: "km"
                }
            }]
        }, 
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

Does not return with calcuated `distance` or sorted by distance. I've also tried using `"location"`.

Here's my mapping: https://21991e47cdc7caa8000.qbox.io/profiles/lead/_mapping

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed to get it working, Please see the difference,

I converted data as json before quering, and added some configuration( changed dataType to json, and request type to **POST**, as we know GET request generally don't have body, only POST request does.

```
var request = {
    sort: [{
        _geo_distance: {
            "pin.location": [
            49.8998, -97.1375],
            order: "asc",
            unit: "km"
        }
    }]
};


$.ajax({
    url: 'https://21991e47cdc7caa8000.qbox.io/profiles/lead/_search',
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(request),
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

I've tested, and it should work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

The example given uses `pin.location`, not `location` or `lead.location`.

Additionally, `pin.location` is an array of length 2, not an object with two fields as you are using it. This seems pretty counter-intuitive to me, as the `location` field in most other api calls is an object like you are using.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://myhostedes.com/profiles/lead/_search", 
    method: "GET", 
    data: {
        "sort": [{
            "_geo_distance": {
                "pin.location": [49.8998, -97.1375], 
                "order": "asc", 
                "unit": "km"
            }
        }]
    }, 
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

**Note:** I don't have access to an elastisearch instance at the moment, so I haven't been able to run this yet.

Comment: Doesn't work. I wonder if I actually need a pin property on the entity? Right now I just have location... Assumed pin was the example entity they were using--this from their docs: "For example, lets take an example of a “pin” that we want to index its location and maybe some tags its associated with". Mapping here all shows "pin" as well though: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-point-type.html

Comment: I've included a link to an ES server where you can try this out. If you can get a request to work there it should work for me as well.

Comment: Looks like it should work: http://www.elasticsearchtutorial.com/spatial-search-tutorial.html

Comment: I agree... Does the request on my server work for you?